# how to print by default the first n row for a pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas

when print a pandas dataframe, how to print the first n row by default?

I find myself frequently doing df.head(10) to view the column names and first a couple of rows.

I prefer when I type 'df', it prints the first n row by default, instead of printing the whole df, which in this case I cannot see the column names.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you may set

```
pd.options.display.max_rows = 10
```

and whenever you do just `df` in your notebook, only `10` rows would be displayed.

You can always set back to the `default` value doing

```
pd.reset_option('display.max_rows')
```

Check [`pd.describe_option('display')`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.describe_option.html) for more information

Comment: Exactly ;) seemed to me OP was constantly doing `df.head` just to peek on the changes to `df`

Answer (score 1):

[Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) `DataFrame.head` using `functools.partial`.

```
from functools import partial
head10 = partial(pd.DataFrame.head, n=10)
```

Now you can either call the function passing your DataFrame as an argument,

```
head10(df)
```

Or, pass the function to `df.pipe` (which internally passes `df` as an argument to your function),

```
df.pipe(head10)
```

To get the first 10 rows by default.

---

The other option is to create a new class that extends `DataFrame` and add your own function (e.g., `headXX`) which internally calls `df.head(n=10)` and returns the result.

See the [subclassing DataFrame](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures) section in the docs.

Comment: Nice answer, but whats the actual gain in doing `head10(df)` rather than `df.head(10)` ?

Comment: @RafaelC One character less. What's the point of this question? (same thing)